# Find status from separate fact table

Tags: sql

This is in snowflake, but I can figure out any other syntax that is similar.
I have a table of employees and the date they received a paycheck

| EMP_ID | Check_dt |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10-7-2021 |
| 2 | 9-28-2021 |
| 1 | 3-1-2021 |

And a table that has employee history for full/part time status changes, and the date the change was made effective

| EMP_ID | Status | Effective Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | F | 1/1/20201 |
| 2 | P | 1/1/2021 |
| 1 | P | 6/1/2021 |

(In this example, employee 1 changed from full to part time halfway through the year)

I want to get the status (F/P) of the employee at the time they received their paycheck.

The output I want is:

| EMP_ID | Check_dt | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10-7-2021 | P |
| 2 | 9-28-2021 | P |
| 1 | 3-1-2021 | F |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you tried yet ?

Comment: I tried a lag function on the employee history table and was able to get an effective from/to for each status, but rather than put a filter in to say check_dt is between those two dates, I'd rather have it just pick the row from the employee history that is immediately before the check date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Select empid, case when t1.chkdate<= (Select 
       max(effect_date) from 
       table2 where empid=t1.empid) then t1.status) end as
       status
    From table1 t1
```

Comment: I like this idea of a case statement! I think the inner select statement would return the max effective_date for that employee from the entire table right? So it would only return the latest status and not the status immediately before the check_dt. So in the suggested output in the first row, it would return F instead of P.